# Java commands in Eclim

Tags: java, eclim

When I run `eclim -? commands`, I get the following output.

```
Available Commands:
    archive_read -f file
    history_add -p project -f file
    history_clear -p project -f file
    history_list -p project -f file
    history_revision -p project -f file -r revision
    jobs [-f family]
    locate_file -p pattern -s scope [-n project] [-f file]
                [-i]
    ping
    problems -p project [-e]
    project_build -p project
    project_by_resource -f file
    project_close -p project
    project_create -f folder [-p name] -n natures [-d depends]
                   [-a args]
    project_delete -p project
    project_import -f folder
    project_info -p project
    project_link_resource -f file
    project_list [-n nature]
    project_move -p project -d dir
    project_nature_add -p project -n nature [-a args]
    project_nature_aliases [-m]
    project_nature_remove -p project -n nature
    project_natures [-p project]
    project_open -p project
    project_refresh -p project
    project_refresh_file -p project -f file
    project_rename -p project -n name
    project_run [-p project] [-v vim_instance_name] [-x vim_executable] [-l]
                [-d] [-c] [-n name]
    project_run_terminate [-l launchid]
    project_setting -p project -s setting [-v value]
    project_settings [-p project]
    project_update -p project [-b buildfile] [-s settings]
    projects
    refactor_redo [-p]
    refactor_undo [-p]
    reload
    setting -s setting
    settings
    settings_update [-s settings]
    shutdown
    workspace_dir
    xml_format -f file -w linewidth -i indent -m fileformat
    xml_validate -p project -f file [-s]
```

I do not see Java commands such as `java_search` or `java_element_doc`. How can I access them?

I have installed eclim version 2.5, and selected "Java Development" in the installation menu.